# Setting up Google Toolbox For Mac for XCode 3.2 iPad project?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ipad

I'm attempting to get google-toolbox-for-mac working with my existing XCode 3.2 iPad project, but am unable to. I'd appreciate suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

I followed the basic project setup found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting

When I try to build my project I get 5 pages of console messages from the RunIPhoneUnitTest.sh script file similar to:

```
objc[19094]: REPLACED: -[NSDictionary boolForKey:]  by category Goodies  (IMP was 0x30c115 (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit), now 0x49c13ab (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message))
```

And the final line of the console is:

```
2010-04-22 17:35:58.535 TestApp[19094:903] SBSetAccelerometerClientEventsEnabled failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

At which point the shell script continues running indefinitely. I did find a patch for iPad development which I used here:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-toolbox-for-mac/browse_thread/thread/d2d773428f9588f0

But that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is discussed here :

http://groups.google.com/group/google-toolbox-for-mac/browse_thread/thread/513a3252d655e1e3/0dbb019a3137a0bd

You should try getting the latest file from the Trunk of the GTM project.

P.S: A woraround is to exclude mainwindow.xib from your test target.

Hope this helps,
Vincent